# Size in Points of photos taken with camera - iPhone 5 or 6 (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, photo

I am trying to find out the point size of the photos taken with the iPhone camera but I can't seem to find any reference manual.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Apple's Iphone documentation. Try https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/